# WebPacker CI Caching Required Folders

Tags: ruby-on-rails, circleci, webpacker

Given a Ruby on Rails project using [WebPacker](https://github.com/rails/webpacker) project, which folders need caching on a CI service to ensure system specs perform optimally? My build pipeline is currently caching `public/packs-test` and `tmp/cache/webpacker`.

Testing locally I see this behaviour:

```
time rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=test # 2.0m
time rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=test # 5.0s
rm -rf ./public/packs-test ./tmp/cache/webpacker
time rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=test # 2.0m
```

This is promising - compilation times are 2 minutes initially, then 5 seconds subsequently. However, on CI I consistently see 2 minute runtimes for asset compilation. Here's the full list of folders I'm caching / restoring between runs:

```
public/packs-test
tmp/cache/webpacker
tmp/yarn
node_modules
```

Note: setting `YARN_CACHE_FOLDER` ENV variable to `tmp/yarn` and using CircleCI.

**Edit:**

To cache using the following snippets are used in the CircleCI configuration.

```
type: cache-restore
keys:
  - assets-{{ .Branch }}-{{ .Revision }}
  - assets-{{ .Branch }}
  - assets

type: cache-save
key: assets-{{ .Branch }}-{{ .Revision }}
paths:
  - public/packs-test
  - tmp/cache/webpacker
  - tmp/yarn
  - node_modules
```

Comment: How do you save and restore your cache? Can you post that particular part of config.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have the same exact problem.

Answer (score 2):

The following steps are working pretty well for me:

```
  - restore_cache:
      name: Restore webpacker cache
      keys:
        - v1-webpacker-{{ .Branch }}-
        - v1-webpacker-

  - restore_cache:
      name: Restore compiled packs
      key: v1-packs-{{ checksum "tmp/cache/webpacker/last-compilation-digest-test" }}

  - save_cache:
      name: Store webpacker cache
      key: v1-webpacker-{{ .Branch }}-{{ epoch }}
      paths:
        - tmp/cache/webpacker

  - save_cache:
      name: Store compiled packs
      key: v1-packs-{{ checksum "tmp/cache/webpacker/last-compilation-digest-test" }}
      paths:
        - public/packs-test
```